# How to use HttpListener to receive byte [] data sent by the client

Tags: c#, streamreader, httplistener

I am very sorry that my c # foundation is limited, but this question has troubled me for many days. I hope the seniors will give me some advice. Thank you very much。
My client sends the message this way:

```
public IEnumerator SetAnchorData(string Url, byte[] data)
{ 
    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Put(Url, data);
    yield return request.Send();
    if (request.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log(request.error);
    }
    else
    {
         text.text += "succeed"+data.Length;
        // Debug.Log("succeed" + data.Length);
    }
    request.Dispose();
}
```

My server reads the data like this：Get the data flow here

```
HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request; 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream);
```

Then you pass the "reader" down to this method to get byte []

```
 `private byte[] ReadLineAsBytes(StreamReader SourceStream)
    {
        var resultStream = new MemoryStream();
        while (!SourceStream.EndOfStream)
         {
            resultStream.WriteByte((byte)SourceStream.Read());
            NUM++;
         }
        Console.Write("It's been read {0} times:", NUM);

        resultStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] dataBytes = new byte[resultStream.Length];
        resultStream.Read(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        return dataBytes;
    }`
```

The result is that the Length of byte [] is less than the Length of the client byte []. I don't know where the problem is. If it is the reading method, please teach me how to do it.
Please help me, please, please, please.

Comment: So your problem is you are not getting all data on server side? Do you have any exceptions/errors which are thrown?

Comment: @Tobias Theel I'm sorry that my problem is not clear enough.The server did not throw exceptions or errors, and in the process of reading the data, several GC yellow points appeared in the process memory. I don't know if this is the reason.

Comment: @Tobias Theel    I think yes, I should have not got all the data.The client sends a data size of about 20MB, while the server value gets about 19MB。